# The mean value of red pixels in an image?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, mean

So today, I have an homework that required to calculate the mean of red pixels in one image, using Engineering: CS101 - SELF PACED Computer Science 101's image as an example. I tried to write the code to do that, but judging from the result, maybe I did something wrong. I'm very grateful if someone can check that for me and help me correct it.

```
image = new SimpleImage("flowers.jpg");

for (pixel: image) {
    red = 0;
    green = 0;
    blue = 0;
    count = 0;
    red =  red + pixel.getRed();
    blue = blue + pixel.getBlue();
    green = green + pixel.getGreen();
    count = count + 1;
    avgred = red / count;
    avggreen= green / count;
    avgblue = blue / count;
}

print(image);
print("Average Red:", avgred);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is incorrect.

To calculate the average you have to sum up all values and then divide that sum by the number of values.

You assign 0 to red and count in every loop iteration so your "average" equals the last pixels red value divided by 1.
So instead of an average you simply get the last pixels values.

Make sure you init your sums and counter befor entering the loop. You only calculate the sum within the loop!

Pseudocode:

```
sum = 0
count = 0
for each pixel:
  sum = sum + pixelvalue
  count = count + 1
end
average = sum / count
```

Comment: Thanks you for your details answer. I'll be careful next time